# Apache Pulsar geo replication not working - GKE

Tags: apache-pulsar

I have two GKE clusters in 2 different regions with Apache Pulsar deployed (using Streamlio app available in marketplace) in both of them. I have added both the clusters to know about each other using

`pulsar-admin clusters create region-2 --url http://<ANOTHER_CLUSTER_IP>:8080 \
                    --broker-url pulsar://<ANOTHER_CLUSTER_IP>:6650`

& the same command in another cluster.

Then I create the tenants & namespaces in cluster `region-1`.

First the tenants

```
pulsar-admin tenants create my-tenant-1 \                                           
           --admin-roles admin --allowed-clusters region-1,region-2
```

Then, the namespace

```
pulsar-admin namespaces set-clusters tenant-1/ns1 --clusters region-1,region-2
```

I dont see the new tenant or the namespace created in `region-1` in replciated `region-2`. Then I tried to give permission to the namespace but I get auth error.

```
$ pulsar-admin namespaces grant-permission my-tenant-1/ns1 \              
                             --actions produce,consume \
                             --role admin
```

I get the below error

```
Authorization is not enabled

Reason: HTTP 501 Not
```

Where am I doing wrong in setting the geo-replication between two different clusters deployed in different regions in gke. Any step I missed?